# What is the simpliest way to insert record based on results of query?

Tags: sql, if-statement

I have a query with a couple of outer joins to get field values for each user. Now I need to insert a field_value row for the eula_date if the stripe_id is not null but the eula_date is null.

Here's my query:

```
select u.id, v1.value as stripe_id, v2.value as eula_date
from hojeh_users as u
left outer join hojeh_community_fields_values as v1
    on v1.user_id = u.id and v1.field_id = 27
left outer join hojeh_community_fields_values as v2
    on v2.user_id = u.id and v2.field_id = 28
```

Here's the result:

```
id  | stripe_id          | eula_date
----+--------------------+-------------------
943 | cus_8c44j6pZ8iN9eA | null 
----+--------------------+-------------------
944 | null               | null
----+--------------------+-------------------
949 | cus_8c2M4zm85BWKsN | 2017-02-01 2:03:57
----+--------------------+-------------------
```

I need to set the

How can I implement an if statement like this:

```
if (v1.value not null && v2.value is null){
     INSERT INTO hojeh_community_fields_values 
     (column1, column2, column3,...columnN) 
     VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

I need to update the field_values table so my results show:

```
id  | stripe_id          | eula_date
----+--------------------+-------------------
943 | cus_8c44j6pZ8iN9eA | 2017-01-01 0:0:0
----+--------------------+-------------------
944 | null               | null
----+--------------------+-------------------
949 | cus_8c2M4zm85BWKsN | 2017-02-01 2:03:57
----+--------------------+-------------------
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO hojeh_community_fields_values 
     (user_id, field_id, value) 
select 
     id, 28, '2017-01-01 0:0:0'
from hojeh_users as u
left outer join hojeh_community_fields_values as v1
    on v1.user_id = u.id and v1.field_id = 27
left outer join hojeh_community_fields_values as v2
    on v2.user_id = u.id and v2.field_id = 28
where v1.value is not null and v2.value is null
```

Comment: is it possible to use the values from the results in the insert statement?

For example, I'd want to make the user_id = value1 in the insert statement.

Comment: Of course you can use every value you want from those returned from your query

Comment: @dawoodman71 have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Aha!  I got it!  I simply select u.id for the user_id column and then pass in '2017-01-01 0:0:0' for the value column. Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: I made a slight edit to your answer. Would that work?

Comment: considering your edit it will insert the u.id in user_id and for the other fields the static values (28 and '2017-01-01 0:0:0') for every record...is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. I am setting a default date for items that don't have a date set. This worked out perfectly and gave me a better understanding of mysql. Thanks again for your help!